# charmap codec characted encoding error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a thai address stored in my table and using a simple query I am getting output as

```
u'35/1-2 8  \u0e16\u0e19\u0e19\u0e23\u0e31\u0e15\u0e19\u0e32\u0e18\u0e34\u0e40\u0e1a\u0e28\u0e23\u0e4c \u0e1a\u0e32\u0e07\u0e01\u0e23\u0e30\u0e2a\u0e2d \u0e40\u0e21\u0e37\u0e2d\u0e07\u0e19\u0e19\u0e17\u0e1a\u0e38\u0e23\u0e35 \u0e19\u0e19\u0e17\u0e1a\u0e38\u0e23\u0e35'
```

I tried to decode it by following command:

```
QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data[i][j].decode('utf-8'))
```

But I am getting this error

```
data[i][j] Error btnManualSearch 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 10-24: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: The output is a unicode object - so why are you trying to ***decode*** it?

Comment: @ekhumoro so i dont need to decode ?

Comment: No - because it has already been decoded.

Comment: @ekhumoro but i still that error

Comment: It works fine for me: `QTableWidgetItem(u'35/1-2 8  \u0e16\u0e19\u0e19\u0e23\u0e31\u0e15\u0e19\u0e32\u0e18\u0e34\u0e40\u0e1a\u0e28\u0e23\u0e4c \u0e1a\u0e32\u0e07\u0e01\u0e23\u0e30\u0e2a\u0e2d \u0e40\u0e21\u0e37\u0e2d\u0e07\u0e19\u0e19\u0e17\u0e1a\u0e38\u0e23\u0e35 \u0e19\u0e19\u0e17\u0e1a\u0e38\u0e23\u0e35')`.